io_uring with `fio` fails on Rocky 9.3 w/kernel 5.14.0-362.18.1.el9_3.x86_64
I've tried various variations of the command:
fio --name=test --ioengine=io_uring --iodepth=64 --rw=rw --bs=4k --direct=1 --size=2G --numjobs=24 --filename=/dev/sdc


lower queue depth
direct set to 1/0
lower numjobs
setenforce 0 just in case SELinux was a problem

but all yield:
test: (g=0): rw=rw, bs=(R) 4096B-4096B, (W) 4096B-4096B, (T) 4096B-4096B, ioengine=io_uring, iodepth=64
...
fio-3.35
Starting 24 processes
fio: pid=71823, err=1/file:engines/io_uring.c:1047, func=io_queue_init, error=Operation not permitted

I have confirmed my host supports io_uring:
[root@r7525-raid tmp]# grep io_uring_setup /proc/kallsyms
ffffffffaa7d4300 t __pfx_io_uring_setup
ffffffffaa7d4310 t io_uring_setup
ffffffffaa7d43a0 T __pfx___ia32_sys_io_uring_setup
ffffffffaa7d43b0 T __ia32_sys_io_uring_setup
ffffffffaa7d4430 T __pfx___x64_sys_io_uring_setup
ffffffffaa7d4440 T __x64_sys_io_uring_setup
ffffffffaae1b3ef t io_uring_setup.cold
ffffffffac2b0180 d event_exit__io_uring_setup
ffffffffac2b0220 d event_enter__io_uring_setup
ffffffffac2b02c0 d __syscall_meta__io_uring_setup
ffffffffac2b0300 d args__io_uring_setup
ffffffffac2b0310 d types__io_uring_setup
ffffffffacabbc68 d __event_exit__io_uring_setup
ffffffffacabbc70 d __event_enter__io_uring_setup
ffffffffacabdd38 d __p_syscall_meta__io_uring_setup
ffffffffacac1cd0 d _eil_addr___ia32_sys_io_uring_setup
ffffffffacac1ce0 d _eil_addr___x64_sys_io_uring_setup

Running with libaio against the same target works without issue. I have not yet read through the code for io_queue_init. Is there a trick to getting io_uring up and running with fio?
I haven't yet read through the code for io_queue_init to see exactly what is failing.

Was met same behavior, the first check if io_uring is disabled or not in sysctl:
sysctl -a | grep io_uring

I suppose it's set to 2: kernel.io_uring_disabled = 2
According to the documentation for the sysctl files in /proc/sys/kernel/:

io_uring_disabled:
Prevents all processes from creating new io_uring instances. Enabling this shrinks the kernel’s attack surface.
0 - All processes can create io_uring instances as normal. This is the
default setting.
1 - io_uring creation is disabled (io_uring_setup() will fail with -EPERM) for unprivileged processes not in the io_uring_group group. Existing io_uring instances can still be used. See the documentation for io_uring_group for more information.
2 - io_uring creation is disabled for all processes. io_uring_setup() always fails with -EPERM. Existing io_uring instances can still be used.

So you need to set it to 0:
sysctl kernel.io_uring_disabled=0

